# Why max ,min and canocalise function not working in c?

Tags: c

I am writing c program to calculate intersection of rectangle but I am not able to get the expected output.The canocalise function,max and min function are not working. Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

//I've provided "min" and "max" functions in

//case they are useful to you

int min (int a, int b) {

if (a < b) {

      return a;

}

return b;

}

int max (int a, int b) {

     if (a > b) {

     return a;

}

return b;

}

//Declare your rectangle structure here!

typedef struct re{

int x,y,width,height;

}rectangle;

rectangle canonicalize(rectangle r) {

//WRITE THIS FUNCTION

if(r.width<0)

{

     r.width=-r.width;

     r.x=r.x-r.width;

}

else if(r.height<0)

{

    r.height=-r.height;

    r.y=r.y-r.height;

 }

 return r;

 }

 rectangle intersection(rectangle r1, rectangle r2) {

//WRITE THIS FUNCTION

 r1.x=max(r1.x,r2.x);

 r1.y=max(r1.y,r2.y);

 r1.width=min(r1.width,r2.width);

 r1.height=min(r1.height,r2.height);

 if(r1.x>r1.width || r1.y>r1.height)

      {

       }

 return r1;

 }

 //You should not need to modify any code below this line

 void printRectangle(rectangle r) {

 r = canonicalize(r);

 if (r.width == 0 && r.height == 0) {

 printf("<empty>\n");

 }

 else {

 printf("(%d,%d) to (%d,%d)\n", r.x,r.y,r.x + r.width,r.y + r.height);

 }

 }

  int main (void) {

  rectangle r1;

  rectangle r2;

  rectangle r3;

  rectangle r4;

  r1.x = 2;

  r1.y = 3;

  r1.width = 5;

  r1.height = 6;

  printf("r1 is ");

  printRectangle(r1);

  r2.x = 4;

  r2.y = 5;

  r2.width = -5;

  r2.height = -7;

  printf("r2 is ");

  printRectangle(r2);

  r3.x = -2;

  r3.y = 7;

  r3.width = 7;

  r3.height = -10;

  printf("r3 is ");

  printRectangle(r3);

  r4.x = 0;

  r4.y = 7;

  r4.width = -4;

  r4.height = 2;

  printf("r4 is ");

  printRectangle(r4);

  //test everything with r1

  rectangle i = intersection(r1,r1);

  printf("intersection(r1,r1): ");

  printRectangle(i);

  i = intersection(r1,r2);

  printf("intersection(r1,r2): ");

  printRectangle(i);

  i = intersection(r1,r3);

  printf("intersection(r1,r3): ");

  printRectangle(i);

  i = intersection(r1,r4);

  printf("intersection(r1,r4): ");

  printRectangle(i);

 //test everything with r2

 i = intersection(r2,r1);

 printf("intersection(r2,r1): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r2,r2);

 printf("intersection(r2,r2): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r2,r3);

 printf("intersection(r2,r3): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r2,r4);

 printf("intersection(r2,r4): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 //test everything with r3

 i = intersection(r3,r1);

 printf("intersection(r3,r1): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r3,r2);

 printf("intersection(r3,r2): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r3,r3);

 printf("intersection(r3,r3): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r3,r4);

 printf("intersection(r3,r4): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 //test everything with r4

 i = intersection(r4,r1);

 printf("intersection(r4,r1): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r4,r2);

 printf("intersection(r4,r2): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r4,r3);

 printf("intersection(r4,r3): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 i = intersection(r4,r4);

 printf("intersection(r4,r4): ");

 printRectangle(i);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;

 }
```

> Current Output:
>
> r1 is (2,3) to (7,9)
>
> r2 is (-1,5) to (4,-2)
>
> r3 is (-2,-3) to (5,7)
>
> r4 is (-4,7) to (0,9)
>
> intersection(r1,r1): (2,3) to (7,9)
>
> intersection(r1,r2): (-1,5) to (4,-2)
>
> intersection(r1,r3): (2,-3) to (7,7)
>
> intersection(r1,r4): (-2,7) to (2,9)
>
> intersection(r2,r1): (-1,5) to (4,-2)
>
> intersection(r2,r2): (-1,5) to (4,-2)
>
> intersection(r2,r3): (-1,7) to (4,-3)
>
> intersection(r2,r4): (-1,7) to (4,0)
>
> intersection(r3,r1): (2,-3) to (7,7)
>
> intersection(r3,r2): (-1,7) to (4,-3)
>
> intersection(r3,r3): (-2,-3) to (5,7)
>
> intersection(r3,r4): (-4,7) to (0,-3)
>
> intersection(r4,r1): (-2,7) to (2,9)
>
> intersection(r4,r2): (-1,7) to (4,0)
>
> intersection(r4,r3): (-4,7) to (0,-3)
>
> intersection(r4,r4): (-4,7) to (0,9)

Note that the max, min and canocalise are not working.

Comment: What is the output you did expect? Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger to see that it does what you expect it to do? You could also shave of parts of the code, or at least skip some of the empty lines, in order to make a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the expected output of `intersection` if the arguments don't overlap?

Comment: And are you sure that it's the `min`, `max` and `canonicalize` functions that are wrong? It's not something missing from your `intersection` function? Something you should quite easy find out if you used a debugger.

Comment: Why did you put a blank line between _each_ line in your code? That doesn't make it more readable.

Comment: Please try explaining your code through commenting lines above not so obvious function declaration. It helps others in helping you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to canonicalize the rectangles inside the `intersection` function before doing anything. There may be other problems, I didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tried doing in intersection function so assuming it is working correctly for you.

```
if(r.width<0)

{

     r.width=-r.width;

     r.x=r.x-r.width;

}

if(r.height<0) // to handle when height and width both are less than zero (r2)

{

    r.height=-r.height;

    r.y=r.y-r.height;

 }
```